# Projection onto a subset in norm space

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a norm space, $S$ be a subset of $X$, for each $x\in X$, denote the set of projection from $x$ to $S$ by $\Pi(x; S):=\{s\in S: \ \|x-s\| =d(x;S)\}$, where $d(x;S):=\inf\{\|x-s\|: \ s\in S\}$.

It is well-known that $\Pi(x;S)$ is nonempty if one of the following assertions holds:
(i) $X$ is finite dimensional and $S$ is closed.
(ii) $X$ is reflexive and $S$ is weakly closed.
Thus, if $X$ is reflexive and $S$ is closed and convex then $\Pi(x; S) \neq \emptyset$, too.

Now, I want to show that the assumption about reflexivity of $X$ is important in the case (ii), my teacher give a counter example below: Consider $\ell^1$ and take $S$ to be the closed convex hull of the set $\{\frac{n+1}{n}e_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $e_n=(0, \ldots, 1_n, 0, \ldots)$. I don't know how to verify that $\Pi(0; S)=\emptyset.$ Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the distance from $0$ to $S$? What is the projection? Note that for a convex set, the projection is a face of $S$ and contains the corner points of the face, which are elements of the defining set.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from a finite dimensional case. In $\mathbb R^2$ the convex hull of $e_1,e_2$ is a segment, each point of which has $l^1$-distance from $0$ exactly $1$. In $\mathbb R^3$, the convex hull of the basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is a triangle, each point of which, has $l^1$-distance from $0$ exactly $1$. And so on... the same argument holds for the space $l^1$, when you take the convex hull of $e_n$. In this case the $l^1$-distance from $S$ to $0$ is constant $1$ and $\Pi(0;S)=S$.

Now, your teacher, pushed the points $e_n$ a little away from zero, by an amount $(n+1)/n$ which tends to $1$. Therefore the infimum of the $l^1$-distances from points of $S$ to $0$ is $1$, but there is no point that realizes such distance.

Comment: I had known something like that, but what you said had not satisfied me at all. What I should do are exactly analysis arguments. Thanks.

Comment: the sentence "the infimum of the $l^1$-distances from points of S to $0$ is $1$" is an analysis argument.

Comment: the distance from $((n+1)e_n)/n$ and $0$ is $(n+1)/n$ which tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty$. What remains to complete formalize is that there is no point of $S$ with $l^1$-norm exactly 1.

Comment: which is achieved by noting that if $x=\sum (t_n (n+1) e_n)/n$ with $t_n\geq 0$ and $\sum t_n=1$ then $||x||_{l^1}> \sum t_n=1$

Comment: As above, we just proved that if  $x \in \textrm{cov} \{\frac{n+1}{n}e_n\}$ then $\|x\| > 1$. Is there any element in the closure of that set has norm equal to 1?

Comment: the convex closure of $\{e_n(n+1)/n\}$ is the set  $\{\sum t_ne_n(n+1)/n$ where $t_n\geq 0$ and $\sum t_n=1\}$. Indeed, the convexity of this set is clear. Suppose $V_k=\sum t_n^ke_n(n+1)/n$ is a sequence in such a set and $V_k\to V$ then $V=\sum a_ne_n$ and is readly checked that $a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum a_n n/(n+1)=1$